# Python GRPC server multiprocessing uses only one process per channel

Tags: multiprocessing, grpc, grpc-python

For my project I've setup a grpc server in Python with multiprocessing according to the [GRPC Github example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/multiprocessing/server.py). The problem is that when I have a single channel sending requests, only one process is receiving the requests.

This problem could be solved by using multiple channels to send requests. But this is not a clean solution. By default the grpc client will also try to use a single connection for multiple channels, so this also needs to be bypassed (See the [comments in the client example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/42b0d01e68dd2588ed73d80cb520a5cb1fcb53e5/examples/python/multiprocessing/client.py#L34)). I also don't want the client side to be required to have a certain connection pool size so the requests are multi-processed correctly.

The tasks that are executes are quite CPU intensive, that is why multi-threading is not enough. In the end I would like to use Linkerd for load balancing. I'm aware that I could just add more pods and let Linkerd load balance instead of relying on `SO_REUSEPORT`, but I don't want to run more pods than necessary.

Is there a good way to create a Python grpc server where multiprocessing is done on request level?